# Font has been changed

Tags: locale, ls, ubuntu-font-family, system-language

[image: Terminal font has been changed]

why has the font of my terminal been changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not your fonts, it's your system locale. run `locale` to get your current locale configuration.

*You can use something like `LC_TIME=fr_FR ls -l` to get France's format in date column as an example if it's available to use on your system.*

You can also use `locale -a` to get a list of available locales. edit `/etc/locale.gen` file to enable your desired locales by removing `#` from any line you want, then run `sudo locale-gen` to generate them.

After all run:

```
sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8
```

to set English locale as your default or change `en_US.utf8` with your desired locale.

Comment: It would be more interesting to list the current locale setting first and then change it....

Comment: Upvoted but I meant if you type `locale` all by itself it lists the current settings.

Comment: In that case Merry Christmas! It's Christmas eve here.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix and Ravexina Merry Christmas!

Comment: @DKBose Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @DKBose Merry Christmas and welcome back to your old name :) Monica's progress with SE is an early Christmas present for you.